# Anchor tag for an ID on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor tag on one page and I want to move to the other page which is index.html page that has a "about us" ID on the div. That id is working from the same page but not when I try to go to it from another page. There are some questions similar to mine but none give me the answer, in one question they said its related to a script but doesnt give a solution of what to do. Can I do this solution through a JAVASCRIPT or JQUERY solution. Please help me, thanks

Comment: How does your _code_ look like ?

Comment: <a href= "index.html#aboutus"> About Us </a>

Comment: It goes to the index.html page but doesn't take me to the #aboutus ID

Comment: Yeah, well show us the code on both pages. I bet your other page's element isn't exactly `<div id="aboutus"></div>`

Comment: You are missing a forward slash  "/" between url and section id. Check the posted answer.

Comment: anyone with a javascript or jquery solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, without adding the "/" works fine. Just make sure that your div's ID is the same as the text after the hash.

```
<div id = "AboutUs">
    <!-- Content Here -->
</div>

<a href = "index.html#AboutUs">Your Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is evident from your comments that you are missing a forward slash between url and section id. Please include "/" so that it is something like `<a href= "index.html/#aboutus">` and not `<a href= "index.html#aboutus">`

Comment: it doesnt work after the slash. its going to the index page right now but just not going to the ID on that page.

Comment: It can possibly be a duplicate id issue. Can you share your page html?

Comment: <div id="aboutus" class="banner-bottom">

Comment: and what is it's url? A live link or a fiddle will be more useful

Comment: the link takes me to the right page but just doesnt take me to the right ID!

Comment: Is there a live link or a fiddle?